# AlertDialogs setCustomTitle not working with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I want to customize TITLE color of V7 AlertDialog. SetCustomTitle() doesnt seems to be working with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog. I can see a blank TITLE like below

[image]

But expected AlertDialog is below

[image]

**Creating Alert Dialog**

```
private void createDialog() {
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( mContext, R.style.TooltipTheme);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new CustomAlertDialogBuilder(ctw);
    builder.setTitle(mTitle);
    builder.setMessage(mMsg);
    builder.setPositiveButton(mOkButton,null);

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
    alert11.show();
    Button positiveButton =       alert11.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.BNPP_Color_Palette_PrimaryBtn));
}
```

**style.xml**

```
  <style name="TooltipTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"></style>
```

**CustomAlertDialogBuilder**

```
public class CustomAlertDialogBuilder  extends AlertDialog.Builder {

private final Context mContext;
private TextView mTitle;
private ImageView mIcon;
private TextView mMessage;

public CustomAlertDialogBuilder(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;

    View customTitle = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.alert_dialog_title, null);
    mTitle = (TextView) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
    mIcon = (ImageView) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    setCustomTitle(customTitle);

    View customMessage = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.alert_dialog_message, null);
    mMessage = (TextView) customMessage.findViewById(R.id.message);
    setView(customMessage);


}

@NonNull
@Override
public AlertDialog.Builder setPositiveButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    return super.setPositiveButton(text, listener);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AlertDialog.Builder setPositiveButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    return super.setPositiveButton(textId, listener);
}

@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setTitle(int textResId) {
    mTitle.setText(textResId);
    return this;
}
@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setTitle(CharSequence text) {
    mTitle.setText(text);
    return this;
}

@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setMessage(int textResId) {
    mMessage.setText(textResId);
    return this;
}

@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setMessage(CharSequence text) {
    mMessage.setText(text);
    return this;
}

@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setIcon(int drawableResId) {
    mIcon.setImageResource(drawableResId);
    return this;
}

@Override
public CustomAlertDialogBuilder setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    mIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
    return this;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the standard title with

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and through

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
```

Have a view with custom title.

Comment: Thanks cherry-wace, let me try this